# Number of solutions to exceedingly contrived congruence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, contest-math

Let $a$ be the number of solutions to$$x^{2011}-96x^{728}-x^{24}+67 \equiv y^{2011}+12718253987182795172957215781251235234235y \pmod{2^{57885161}-1}$$where $x$ and $y$ are integers in-between $0$ and $2^{57885161}-2$. Prove that $a$ is between$$2^{57885161}-2013+2010\cdot 2009 \cdot \sqrt{2^{57885161}-1}$$and$$2^{57885161}-1+2010\cdot 2009 \cdot \sqrt{2^{57885161}-1}.$$

Comment: I think the only information we need is that $x$ and $y$ are of degree 2011 and that $2^57885161-1$ is prime.

Comment: Wow, check this out:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number

Comment: Yeah, this couldn't have been a $2011$ contest problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is amazing is the lower bound. For upper bounds there is the Hasse-Weil bound and improvements on it, check out this [paper](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/pointscurves-moscow.pdf). I am not aware of any lower bounds that are that good so I leave it to the specialists from here.